# How to avoid overwriting of jar files in maven-assembly files

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I am completely new to maven.

And I have the following maven-assembly file to debug.

```
<assembly>
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <!-- Adds dependencies to zip package under lib directory -->
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>startup.*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <!-- adds jar package to the root directory of zip package -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Issue with the above file is that the underlying application needs to get jars from two related projects.

Both these projects have some jars with same names.

When I execute mvn clean assembly:assembly, it copes all the jars from the two projects into one folder.

Obviously, this overwrites some jar files and that is where the problem begins.

Due to this, I start getting ClassNotFound errors.

Please help me in sorting this out.

Also, I am not sure were the variables ${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory} and ${project.build.directory} are being defined.

I have searched the entire source code for this but no good.

Now I suspect these to be some maven specific variables, but I am at a loss to understand this.

If you have some great maven tutorial for an absolute fresher to maven, please do provide.

Answer (score 1):

In order to start using maven you should read this first: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html.

In second instance you can read also some examples: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html